# How do I reset my display to default

Tags: interface

V2.9.2  Mac OSX 10.13.6
Noob here.
Started following a tutorial and was in the Preference window.
Thought I was saving and clicked some dots in the bottom left of the window.
Now I have miniscule type, too tiny to navigate and try and correct.
I tried reinstalling but I still have to same issue.
[image]

Comment: maybe first take a look into the Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display > Resolution Scale?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Can I just point you to, "Now I have miniscule type, too tiny to navigate and try and correct." The image is a clue. I would have done as suggested BUT it is too tiny to navigate. Frustration rather than sarcasm.

Comment: so you can't even go into the Preferences?

Comment: By dint of a magnifying glass, changing screen resolution, using the accessibility function and lots of trial and errer I managed to fix it myself. I'll get my coat.

Comment: Too tiny to read is the clue. Sorted it out, see post below. Got my coat and in the hallway approaching the exit.

Comment: Yes I thought about changing the resolution. So how did it happen? Because of a involuntary shortcut? Did you fix it with the Preferences?

Answer (score 2):

That setting can be changed in the Preferences. Go to Edit > Preferences, then adjust your Resolution Scale. That should help!

[image]

There's a keyboard shortcut to change it on the fly so you may have done that by accident.

Comment: A quick link to the keyboard shortcut would have saved my fat lazy fingers the trouble of searching. Will do a search now.